# Can we open an App in iOS using voice?

Tags: ios, voice-recognition

Basically I would like to turn on my app when in a certain environment(club scene), can an app be turned on in iOS using an algorithm?

Regards,

Feras A.

Comment: You can bring it to the user's attention with a small app icon in the down left corner of the lock screen with geofencing if they is an option. You can probably based on coordinates also send notifications to the user which allow him or her to open the app.

Answer (score 0):

iOS is not in favor of keeping the mic open all the time to record everything. So I dont see this is possible anytime soon.

You have to have an app that records the voice all the time and does a lot of FFT in order to determine what kind of scene you are in.

Unless your app is a music streaming app unfortunately app will be suspended by OS sooner or later so you cannot listen all the time.

Comment: What about how Siri can now be turned on my voice on the new iPhone? does that mean it is listening all the time?

Comment: Yes, if phone is responding voice commands without touch, that means mic is listening for certain phrases

Comment: how do you do that?